# Facebook Log In/ Sign up stopped work after updating fbsdk to 0.7.0

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fbsdk

I have updated react-native-fbsdk to 0.7.0 after that log in/sign up in IOS stoped working, it doesn't show any errors, just show empty screen after the pressing button "Continue".

In Android everything works fine.

Here is my code for sign in.

```
import {
  LoginManager,
  AccessToken,
  GraphRequest,
  GraphRequestManager,
} from 'react-native-fbsdk'

const provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider

const loginPermissions = ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_birthday', 'user_location']
const userUri = '/me?fields=id,name,last_name,email,gender,birthday,location,picture.type(large)'

/**
 * @returns {Promise} with firebase user
 */
export const signIn = () => {
  return LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(loginPermissions)
    .then((loginResult) => {
      if(loginResult.isCancelled) {
        console.log("Login result is cancelled ", loginResult.isCancelled)
        return null
      }else{
        //return a Promise to get the access token
        console.log("Login Access Token", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken())
        return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
      }
    }).then((token) => {
      let credential = provider.credential(token.accessToken)
      //return a promise to sign into firebase
      return firebaseApp.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
    })
}

export const getUserData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let request = new GraphRequest(userUri, null, (err, graphResult) => {
      if(err) {
        reject(err)
      }

      resolve(graphResult)
    })
    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(request).start()
  })
}
```

What can be the problem? and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads) for iOS to the latest version -  4.31.1 and then adding [manually files to Xcode](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/#download) helped me.